# Deleting custom functions in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, python, field-calculator, qgis-custom-function

Is there a way to delete custom functions (e.g. *extractZipCode* in the screenshot below) from the QGIS Field Calculator without having to look into the expressions folder on disc?

I know I can simply delete the Python script in this folder:

```
C:\Users\admin\.qgis2\python\expressions
```

But is there a way to actually do it from within QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Would be nice if they added a `Delete file` button next to `New file`. But if you want to do it within QGIS then I guess you could use the **Python Console**: `import os`; `os.remove('C:/Users/admin/.qgis2/python/expressions/example.py')`

Answer (score 2):

QGIS 3.14 has a remove button to the Function Editor tab. [Changelog](https://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.14/#feature-ability-remove-custom-functions-fix-27513)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way which I found to do that is to erase the definition of the function from the *Function Editor* tab and you won't see the function name under the 'Custom' functions list .

Comment: You mean just erasing the entire content? Or removing the name (*New File*), which is created on the left-hand side in the Function Editor? In the latter case, how would you do that? Right-clicking does not seem to work...

Comment: By erasing the definition I meant to erase the contents of the file. The latter functionality is not yet available in QGIS.